# Complex Model-related logic called via Rake: where to keep it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, rake

One of the rake tasks in our RoR application is pretty complex - it interacts with external APIs and updates separate Rails model containing some social metrics. That task and it's functions are called exclusively from cron, but the task itself contains some model-related logic (like creating needed associations with other models).

So my question is, where should we put all the code that provides the logic? Keep it in a task? Move it to model's class methods? Which is better, fat model and skinny rake task, or the other way around?

Comment: Though I guess it boils down to 'whichever way is easier to test'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion all API-related classes should be separated and lie in `app/services/` directory, moreover, I'd create [adapters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for each of these classes(for example if external API will change version case - [I wrote a post about this approach](http://rustamagasanov.com/blog/2014/11/16/adapter-design-pattern-usage-in-rails-application-on-examples/) if you are interested). Next, if your logic hits multiple models, I'd put it into `app/usecases`, [there is a great article about structuring Rails app](http://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2013/10/06/structuring-rails-applications/).

So I suggest you to split everything, according to [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). This way it would be easy to test and maintain the code.

Example:

- rake task calls `SomeComplexCreatorUsecase.new(options).run`
- `SomeComplexCreatorUsecase` creates needed objects and relations
- `SomeComplexCreatorUsecase` calls `ExternalApi1Service.get_some_data`
- `ExternalApi1Service.get_some_data` calls `ExternalApi1Adapter.get_some_data`(optional)
- `SomeComplexCreatorUsecase` gets all needed data and perform remaining calculations

Answer (score 0):

I'd look to make this (and most things) "just Ruby." In other words, once it reaches a certain level of complexity, outsource it to its own file/module/whatever, and inject any dependencies you require.

So you could create a separate module that lives in `/lib`, or wherever you think most appropriate.

This also simplifies testing.